# View not updating based on @ObservedObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, observable

i'm facing the problem of UI is not updated

In the following code, an observed object is updated but the View that observes it is not. Any idea why?

Here is the UI code:

```
@main
struct watchkitapp_Watch_AppApp: App {
    @StateObject private var  manager = WorkoutTracking()
    @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(manager)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: WorkoutTracking
    
    init() {
        print("AWAKE")
        WorkoutTracking.authorizeHealthKit()
        WorkoutTracking.shared.startWorkOut()
        WatchKitConnection.shared.startSession()
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Live heart rate: \(manager.heartRate)") <=== UI here is not updated
            
            Button {
                print("Start workout session!")
                WorkoutTracking.shared.startWorkOut()
            } label: {
                Text("Start Workout")
            }.padding()
            
            Button {
                print("Stop workout session!")
                WorkoutTracking.shared.stopWorkOut()
            } label: {
                Text("Stop Workout")
            }.padding()
        }
    }
}
```

WorkoutTracking class - ObservableObject:

```
class WorkoutTracking: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    static let shared = WorkoutTracking()
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    let configuration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
    var workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession!
    var workoutBuilder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder!
    @Published var heartRate: Double <==== HERE
    
    weak var delegate: WorkoutTrackingDelegate?
    
    override init() {
        self.heartRate = 0.0 <==== HERE
        super.init()
    }
    
}

extension WorkoutTracking {
    private func handleSendStatisticsData(_ statistics: HKStatistics) {
        switch statistics.quantityType {
        case HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate):
            let heartRateUnit = HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute())
            let value = statistics.mostRecentQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit)
            let roundedValue = Double( round( 1 * value! ) / 1 )
            delegate?.didReceiveHealthKitHeartRate(roundedValue)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.heartRate = roundedValue } <==== The value is updated here
            print("Heart Rate: \(self.heartRate)")
            
        case HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount):
            guard let stepCounts = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount) else {
                return
            }
            let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
            
            let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepCounts, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { [weak self] (_, result, error) in
                guard let weakSelf = self else {
                    return
                }
                var resultCount = 0.0
                guard let result = result else {
                    print("Failed to fetch steps rate")
                    return
                }
                
                if let sum = result.sumQuantity() {
                    resultCount = sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                    weakSelf.delegate?.didReceiveHealthKitStepCounts(resultCount)
                } else {
                    print("Failed to fetch steps rate 2")
                }
            }
            healthStore.execute(query)
            return
        default:
            return
        }
    }
......
}
```

I tried but did not find out what's wrong, in console, the heart rate value is updated every 5 seconds but the UI is not updated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: one thing is you need to move authorize and start from the ContentView init because that is called many times, move it to an action like you start button and check if already authorized and check if already started.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two objects with different states one with environment and one with singleton, that's why your view isn't updating so use either environment object or singlenton object.

Answer (score 0):

I see the heatRate state is updated via handleSendStatisticsData(_ statistics: HKStatistics). I don't see this function called within the code provided.